# Override Product Price Template In Magento

Tags: magento

I'm trying to hide the price for all products in Magento for both the Product and Grid page. I created a custom module to update the layout, the config.xml is as follows:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <ABC_XYZ>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </ABC_XYZ>
    </modules>

    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <killprice>
                    <file>killprice.xml</file>
                </killprice>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>

</config>
```

I added the killprice.xml as follows:

```
<layout>


    <default>
        <block type="catalog/product_price_template" name="catalog_product_price_template"  template="killprice/price.phtml"  />
    </default>

    <killprice_index_index>
        <block type="catalog/product_price_template" name="catalog_product_price_template"  template="killprice/price.phtml"  />
    </killprice_index_index>

</layout>
```

But the killprice/price.phtml is not being rendered and I get the normal price template. I am a bit suspicious about the tags in killprice.xml layout file, am I overriding the price template the right way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be what you are looking for…

```
<layout>
    <default>
         <reference name="catalog_product_price_template">
            <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>simple</type><block>catalog/product_price</block><template>killerprice/price.phtml</template></action>
            <!-- duplicate for each product type you need to handle i.e. change the value of the <type> node" -->
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Have a look in `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract` to see why this works

Comment: <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>simple</type><block>catalog/product_price</block><template>namespace/catalog/product/simple_price.phtml</template></action>
             <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>bundle</type><block>catalog/product_price</block><template>namespace/catalog/product/bundle_price.phtml</template></action>             
                                                                                                           this didnt worked for me